# Is there a Lubuntu, Centos equvialent...Centos that runs lxde out of the box?

Tags: centos, distribution-choice, distributions, lxde

Are there any CentOS distros that run LXDE out of the box?  I want to use CentOS for a server I'm throwing together instead of Ubuntu, but I want to be able to run LXDE as the system I'm using has kind of low system specs.

Comment: Any reason why `yum install lxde` is not enough? Why do you need this out of the box? If you're setting up a server and prefer CentOS I assume you know your way around the basics of a Linux system, setting up a new desktop environment is trivial.

Comment: if you're putting a desktop environment on it, it's really a *server*.

Comment: It's not server hardware it's a desktop system I'm going to install FOG on to image some machines.  If it doesn't exist I'll use lubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Fedora LXDE Spin](http://spins.fedoraproject.org/lxde/), where Fedora is the base of Red Hat, and CentOS is just a rebranding/copy of Red Hat.

The only difference: Fedora has very recent software which sometimes is like beta. But if you use the Fedora release from last year, you can add all the security and bugfixing updates to have a somewhat more stable system.

Only problem: Support for Fedora systems is only one year.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following to search it appears not.

http://distrowatch.com/search.php

You should follow the advice in the comments and just #yum install lxde

[Here](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Installation) are more instructions if needed.